# ReactJS Can not get a Ref to a Class Component using ref callback

Tags: reactjs, preact, react-ref

I'm trying to get a ref to a child component (Class component) from a parent component, I faced two issues:

```
Parent component

private childRef: RefObject<any> = React.createRef();

<Child ref={this.childRef} />
```

1. The ref callback does not fire and get a null `{current: null}` in my reference.
2. React-dev-tools warns me of passing ref from a functional component, but my child component is a class component..

`react_devtools_backend.js:2273 Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?`

Can anyone help ?

FYI This issue occurred while migrating my app from PReact to React.
In Preact, the ref used to pass correctly:

Parent

```
 <Child ref={(ref: any) => {
                      if (ref && ref._component) {
                        this.childRef = ref._component._component
                      }
                    }}
</Child>
```

Comment: What does Child look like?

Comment: @Yatrix The Child component is a class component:

`
class Child extends React.Component <Iprops, Istate>{}
`

Answer (score 0):

You have to Forward Ref.

```
const Child = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <div ref={ref} >
    ....
  </div>
))
```

The ref is not passed from functional component to it's DOM element automatically. So you have to pass it manually. More about it https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

Answer (score -2):

Wrap it inside div. Try This:

```js
Parent component

private childRef: RefObject<any> = React.createRef();

<div ref={this.childRef} >
<Child />
<div>
```